# Files and folders disappearing after using mv

Tags: mv

Hi firstly I have looked through other questions similar to mine and I couldn't find relevant answers to me.

Running Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS Command Line

In my home directory I have 2 folders

11100

- world

server

- contains server files for a minecraft server

While in the home directory, I used the command `mv 11100/world ../server` and after `cd server/` there was no world folder and none of the files in the world folder were there. I did the same thing using a text file to test it and it also was not found.

I used the locate package and after updating the database I did `locate level.dat` while in my home directory which is a file in the world folder and it said it was found in `/server/level.dat`but I could not see it, this was also the case for every other file found in the world folder. I tried `ls -a` and it was also not found. I also tried `nano level.dat` to see whether I can edit it but also to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Were you in "your home" directory (`/home/username`) or your "home" directory (`/home`)? Did you run the `mv` command with root privileges?

Comment: your `server` folder is up one level from where you think it is. from your home directory try `ls -l ../server`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you did `mv 11100/world ../server` you moved the server folder one level up so to find your folder do `cd ../` from your home directory